# How do I get my function to find my input arguments?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function that would format my input text using predefined styles.

```js
const icons = {
    user: {'icon_cod': '%c  %c', 'font_icon': 'font-family:"Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900;'} // declare my icon
}
const txt_styles = {
    texto: {'style': 'color:red; font-family: "Open Sans"; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px;', // Format my text and icon
            'icon_style': 'color:blue;'}
}

function icon_construct(icon_chosen,text,style) {
    txt_formatted = '' 
    if (icon_chosen in icons && style in txt_styles) { // Check the input 
        txt_formatted = icons.icon_chosen['icon_cod'] + text, icons.icon_chosen['font_icon'] + txt_styles.style['icon_style'], txt_styles.style['style']
    } return txt_formatted // Returns formatted text
}

console.log(icon_construct('user','Hello World','body'));
```

However the exit is returns this error to me:

[image: Error Returned]

The expected output would be this

[image]

To exemplify how formatting happens

```js
    //Run in the browser console
    console.log ('%c Red %c Blue','color: red; ','color: blue; ')
```

The styles follow the order in which the elements were declared
Function does not find the value of the argument

Comment: Sorry but Mr. executed the console.log script ('%c Red', 'color: red;')? It is just a simple statement of inline css, as for the icon it is a font https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

Comment: You're right. I removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Note that snippet cannot print design to console, take a look at the devtools to see the result):

```js
const
    icons = {
        user: {
            iconCode: '%c  %c',
            fontIcon: 'font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"; font-weight: 900;'
        }
    },
    textStyles = {
        text: {
            style: 'color: red; font-family: "Open Sans"; font-weight: 700; font-size: 15px;',
            iconStyle: 'color: blue;'
        }
    },
    iconConstruct = (iconChosen, text, style) =>
        iconChosen in icons && style in textStyles ? [
            icons[iconChosen].iconCode + text,
            icons[iconChosen].fontIcon + textStyles[style].iconStyle,
            textStyles[style].style
        ] : [];

console.log(...iconConstruct('user', 'Hello World', 'text'));
```

Comment: Excellent was just what I needed, mainly due to the much more organized code structure. But I was in doubt about the operation '...' why did you choose it, and why put the 'returned value' in brackets?
My second question would be to separate my values with ' , ' implied that javascript doesn't understand how multiple values, like python, would have a solution for this, in addition to the one you developed?

Comment: @luismatheus The most correct way to use the console design is to send it a string as the first argument, and for each instance of ```c%```, send it another string argument that represents the design for that instance. In your case, you need 3 arguments - the text string, and 2 design strings. Therefore, I returned a set of 3 values, which I decomposed in order using the spread operator (```...```).

Answer (score 1):

There is no prop named `icon_chosen`. You need the square bracket syntax here: `txt_formatted = icons.icon_chosen`.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to understand like this, assume you have an object as given:

```
obj = { 1:{'color':'black','height':'20px'}    
        2:{'color':'white','height':'60px'}
       }
```

So if you want access the color property it can be done by

```
obj[1].color
```

in your case:

```
icons[icon_chosen].icon_cod
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no prop `icon_chosen` for `icon`
here `icon_chosen` contain value `user`
so by using `icon[icon_chosen]` you will have user object value.

try below function

```
function icon_construct(icon_chosen,text,style) {
    if ( icons.hasOwnProperty(icon_chosen) && txt_styles.hasOwnProperty(style)) { // Check the input
        console.log(icons[icon_chosen]['icon_cod'] + text, icons[icon_chosen]['font_icon'] + txt_styles[style]['icon_style'], txt_styles[style]['style'])
    }
}
```

[image: working example (user icon missing - i guess for css is missing in my local )]

working example (user icon missing - i guess for css is missing in my local )